# Send SMS via API with Python

Tags: python, soap, sms, suds

Send request with python is easy.

```
 xml = \
  """
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <request>
       <head>
        <operation>submit</operation>
        <login>user</login> 
        <password>pass</password> 
        <title>title</title> 
        <isbulk>false</isbulk> 
        <scheduled>2018-04-04 17:55:05</scheduled>
        <controlid>188</controlid>
     </head>
     <body>
      <msisdn>676775</msisdn>
      <message>test from code</message> </body>
  </request>"""



 headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'} # set what your server accepts
 req = requests.post('sms.xxxx.xxx/bulksms/api', data=xml, 
 headers=headers)

 print req.text 

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><head> . 
 <responsecode>300</responsecode></head></response>
```

Using suds

```
from suds.client import Client
url="https://xxxxx/bulksms/api"
client = Client(url)
print client #there isnt any service
```

But I can send sms using api test application. How can I send sms using python code? Why I can send using application but it is always return 300 in code?

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python)

Comment: @Adonis twilio is great, but I have to use this firm's api

Comment: Is there a publicly available documentation of their API?

Comment: @Adonis No, but in document they said about xml and response codes, that I have written above